# Override as_json or to_json model class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I'd like to modify the classname when calling to_json on an AR model.

i.e.

```
Book.first.to_json
 #=> "{\"book\":{\"created_at\":\"2010-03-23 

Book.first.to_json(:root => 'libro')
 #=> "{\"libro\":{\"created_at\":\"2010-03-23
```

Is there an option to do this?

Comment: I don't know about overriding to_json but you can set ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false and it won't output the root node, you could then add whatever root node you like.

Answer (score 29):

To be compatible with Rails 3, override `as_json` instead of `to_json`. It was introduced in 2.3.3:

```
def as_json(options={})
  { :libro => { :created_at => created_at } }
end
```

Make sure `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false`. When you call `to_json`, behind the scenes `as_json` is used to build the data structure, and `ActiveSupport::json.encode` is used to encode the data into a JSON string.

Answer (score 7):

Since 3.0.5, at least, you do now have the option of passing a :root option to the to_json call. Here is the source of the as_json method on active record now.

```
def as_json(options = nil)
    hash = serializable_hash(options)

    if include_root_in_json
      custom_root = options && options[:root]
      hash = { custom_root || self.class.model_name.element => hash }
    end

    hash
end
```

So to use this just `@obj.to_json(:root => 'custom_obj')`

Answer (score 0):

You could override the default to_json method in your model, build up a hash of the attributes you want, and then call the hash's to_json method on that.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_json
    { :libro => { :created_at => created_at } }.to_json
  end

end

#=> "{\"libro\":{\"created_at\":\"2010-03-26T13:45:28Z\"}}"
```

Or if you want all of the records attributes...

```
def to_json
  { :libro => self.attributes }.to_json
end
```