# Why are my associations not rendered to JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to control the JSON rendering of a user object in Rails 3.0.2. Here's the relevant model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :employer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  def as_json(options={}) 
    super(options.merge(:include => [:employer, :roles])) 
  end
end
```

Here's the JSON representation I get:

```
{"user":{"employer":{},"roles":[{},{},{}],"email":"user.user@example.com"}}
```

This user **does** have three roles, so somehow the `:include` statement is looking up the association, but the role and employer objects are not getting converted to JSON.

If I had an `as_json` to either of those models, returning garbage, it still doesn't show up.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? (It wasn't rendering anything for the associations until I upgraded from Rails 3.0.0, which I learned to do from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924884/overriding-as-json-has-no-effect).)

Comment: Did you include them in your query?

Comment: @Maz - not originally, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My workaround

I'm still not sure why it didn't work, but my workaround is to build the representation I wanted manually.

```
  def serializable_hash(options={}) 
    hash_info = super(options) 
    hash_info[:employer] = {:name => employer.name}
    hash_info[:roles] = roles
    hash_info
  end
```

I'm using `serializable_hash` because that is a more general-purpose method from which Rails can generate JSON or XML or whatever. But the method works the same if you change the name to `as_json`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try:
`to_json(:include => [:employer, :roles])` in place of as_json

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything.